# В Python 3.4.3 отсутствует библиотека libxml2

Tags: python, python-3.x

После установки Python 3.4.3 на Windows 8.1 (x64) обнаружилось, что библиотека libxml2 попросту отсутствует (в Python 3.5.0b3 тоже, ну это так, к слову). Кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобной проблемой? Как добавить ее в Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На сколько я знаю, в libxml2 действительно нет поддержки python3. Используйте libxml.